# Lead vs Carbon Properties

Tags: periodic-table

Lead and carbon are part of the same group on the periodic table, so they have the same number of valence electrons. However, their chemical and physical properties are dramatically different. But why and how?

Comment: Compare with Si, Ge, and Sn…

Comment: Consider what happens as the outer electron shell gets farther from the nucleus, screened by the inner shells. Also consider the definition of a metal, in relation to outer electrons.

Comment: I understand that the differences in ionization energy, electron affinity and electronegativity heavily impact the behaviour of these elements but how does it impact their physical properties?

Comment: [Why would graphite have been confused with lead?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/44014)

Comment: @user121618, physical properties are also determined by the electronic structure by large. When the bonds are strong, the material is tough; when they are not, the material is brittle or soft. Similarly, the conductivity is determined ultimately by the atomic radii, ionization energy and electron affinity (the last two also define the electronegativity and polarizability).